# How to know when elasticsearch is ready for query after adding new data?

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch

I am trying to do some unit tests using elasticsearch. I first start by using the index API about 100 times to add new data to my index. Then I use the search API with aggs. The problem is if I don't pause for 1 second after adding data 100 times, I get random results. If I wait 1 second I always get the same result.

I'd rather not have to wait x amount of time in my tests, that seems like bad practice. Is there a way to know when the data is ready?

I am waiting until I get a success response from elasticsearch /index api already, but that is not enough it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd suggest you to index your documents with a single `bulk` query : it would save some time because of less http/tcp overhead.

**To answer** your question, you should consider using the `refresh=true` parameter (or `wait_for`) while indexing your 100 documents.

As stated in documentation, it would :

> Refresh the relevant primary and replica shards (not the whole index)
>   immediately after the operation occurs, so that the updated document
>   appears in search results immediately

More about it here :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html